# PHP script not writing properly to file

Tags: php, html

I recently started studying PHP coding, so far everything was fine, until I tried to make a php script that stores data from a HTML form into a textfile. The situation is the following: on the form there is a simple textbox in which email address in this case has to be written with a submit button below, on the php script I have email: printed as text and than the variable which should be pulled from the form. The text email: is printed but the actual address, written in the form is nowhere to be found. Below is the code for both the form and the script. One more thing, the target text file in which the info is written was created, so the script has permission to write in the directory. The php version of the server is 5.2 and the apache version is 2.2.19 (Unix). The host service I use is 000webhost.com

form code:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<form action = "email_script2.php" method = "GET">
<p>Email Address: <input type = "text" name = "text" name = "email" size = "30"/> 
</p>
<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Submit"/> 
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

script code:

```
<?PHP
$email = $_GET['email'];
$file_handle = fopen("testfile.txt", "w");
$file_contents = "email:" . $email;
fwrite($file_handle, $file_contents);
fclose($file_handle);
ini_set('error_reporting', 'on'); error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input text should have only one "name" attribute like this :

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<form action = "email_script2.php" method = "GET">
<p>Email Address: <input type = "text" name = "email" size = "30"/> 
</p>
<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Submit"/> 
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

What do you mean by `The text email: is printed but the actual address, written in the form is nowhere to be foud` ?
You mean you fill your email in the form and you get nothing in your file ?

You can try printing it onscreen to check if it has correct value :

```
<?PHP
$email = $_GET['email'];
echo $email // checking if it has correct value
$file_handle = fopen("testfile.txt", "w");
$file_contents = "email:" . $email;
fwrite($file_handle, $file_contents);
fclose($file_handle);
ini_set('error_reporting', 'on'); error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
```

Comment: I mean that in this line 

    $file_contents = "email:" . $email;

there are two things to put in the text file, email: and the actual email address, email: is there but the address is not there, thanks for the answer I'll give it a try

Comment: Ok then as you said no problem with writting to the file. Your $email variable may have been empty because of that double "name" attribute in your html code.